# Trouble calling contract functions from another contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I have a roulette smart contract, that uses another smart contract to provide it with random numbers. The issue i'm having is during compilation, i get the error:

TypeError: Type contract IRandomNumberGenerator is not implicitly convertible to expected type address.
project:/contracts/Roulette.sol:34:29:
randomNumberGenerator = IRandomNumberGenerator(randomNumberGenerator);

I'm not exactly sure where i'm going wrong, i've seen this code used in other contracts. Here is my full code, any help would be much appreciated.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED"

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "./IRandomNumberGenerator.sol";

contract Roulette is Ownable {

  using SafeERC20 for IERC20;

  IERC20 public gameToken;

  uint256[100] internal randomNumbers;

  IRandomNumberGenerator internal randomNumberGenerator;

  // ensure caller is the random number generator contract
  modifier onlyRandomGenerator() {
    require(msg.sender == address(randomNumberGenerator), "Only random generator");
    _;
  }

  constructor(address tokenAddress) {
    gameToken = IERC20(tokenAddress);
  }

  function setRandomNumberGenerator(address randomNumberGenerator) external onlyOwner {
    randomNumberGenerator = IRandomNumberGenerator(randomNumberGenerator);
  }

  function getRandomNumber() internal onlyOwner returns (uint) {
    uint result = randomNumbers[randomNumbers.length-1];
    delete randomNumbers[randomNumbers.length-1];

    return result;
  }

  function numberGenerated(uint randomNumber) external onlyRandomGenerator {
    randomNumbers = expand(randomNumber);
  }

  // generate 100 random numbers from the random number seed
  function expand(uint256 randomValue) public pure returns (uint256[] memory expandedValues) {
    expandedValues = new uint256[](100);
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      expandedValues[i] = uint256(keccak256(abi.encode(randomValue, i)));
    }
    return expandedValues;

    // TODO - ensure random numbers are roulette numbers
  }
}






// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED"

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBase.sol";
import "./IRoulette.sol";

contract RandomNumberGenerator is VRFConsumerBase {

  address public roulette;
  bytes32 internal keyHash;
  uint256 internal fee;
  uint256 internal randomResult;

  // modifier to check if caller of owner is the admin
  modifier onlyRoulette() {
    require(msg.sender == roulette, "Caller to function is not the roulette contract");
    _;
  }

  constructor(address _roulette) 
    VRFConsumerBase(
        0xa555fC018435bef5A13C6c6870a9d4C11DEC329C, // VRF Coordinator
        0x84b9B910527Ad5C03A9Ca831909E21e236EA7b06  // LINK Token
    )
  {
    keyHash = 0xcaf3c3727e033261d383b315559476f48034c13b18f8cafed4d871abe5049186;
    fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18;
    
    roulette = _roulette;
  }
  
  function getRandomNumber() public onlyRoulette returns (bytes32 requestId) {
    require(LINK.balanceOf(address(this)) >= fee, "Not enough LINK - fill contract with faucet");
    return requestRandomness(keyHash, fee);
  }

  function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 requestId, uint256 randomness) internal override {
    randomResult = randomness;
    IRoulette(roulette).numberGenerated(randomResult);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out the issue was having the same name for both the parameter and the variable.

Updated the function to:

```
  function setRandomNumberGenerator(address _randomNumberGenerator) external onlyOwner {
    randomNumberGenerator = IRandomNumberGenerator(_randomNumberGenerator);
  }
```